# Karma: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I've downloaded angular through bower and have included it in files in the conf file. [File Structure/Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBO5C.png).  When I run karma, the tests say: `angular is not defined`.  I thought including it in the Files section was supposed to resolve it as a dependency.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspell bower folder name, it should be `bower_components` instead of `bower-components`. Underscore, not dash.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid.  I don't know how long I've been looking at that same exact thing and not realizing.  Thank you.